# How to ensure encryption in transit while connecting to Netsuite via ODBC?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, odbc, netsuite

I have been trying to find a solution for pulling data from Netsuite into our data warehouse using python and ODBC connector provided by Netsuite. How can I ensure encryption in transit while connecting to Netsuite via ODBC?

I haven't been able to find any resources on this topic.